# What's a convenient way of showing the latest version of a deleted file?

Tags: git

I can do:

```
git-showlatest(){ git show $(git log -p -- "$1" |grep commit|head -n1|cut -d\  -f2):"$1"; }
```

as a bash function.

Is there a better way?

Comment: `git log -n1 --pretty=format:"%H" -- filename` should give you the full commit hash that you can give `git show`. The output of `git log -n1 -p -- filename` may be helpful too.

Comment: `git show $(git rev-list -1 -- "$1"):"$1"` should be enough.

Comment: Note on my solution: it works for _deleted_ files. The name of the function, `git-showlatest()`, doesn't convey that. It implies that you want the latest version of the file, whether it exists in the current revision or not (and if that's the case, I don't know if you care about work tree vs index vs HEAD). So if that's what you're after, I suggest opening a separate question to clarify that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you're missing a caret (`^`):

```
git-showlatest() 
{ 
    git show "$(git log -p -- "$1" |grep commit|head -n1|cut -d\  -f2)^:$1"
}
```

You need the caret because in the revision in question, the file doesn't exist - because it was deleted, so you want the version that existed in the revision before that.

But as @zedfoxus said, you don't need to do this parsing (and you can also use `xargs`):

```
git-showlatest() 
{ 
    git log -n 1 --pretty='format:%H' -- "$@" \
        | xargs -I '{}' git show "{}^:$1"
}
```

Comment: You're right about the caret, I also forgot it in my comment / deleted answer. Good point.